# Google API Service Account Authorization Error

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I am using the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) client to connect to Google Drive using a Service Account.  Most of the time it works, but every so often (say if I sit here an refresh the page over and over it's every 5th to 10th time), I receive a `Google_Service_Exception` with the message `unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method`.  The error only occurs if the `$this->drive_service->files->listFiles()` code is present.  It does not occur if I use the Service Account directly rather than using `setSubject()` to impersonate another user.

```
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $this->client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
        $this->client->setSubject('xxxx');
        $this->drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
        $files = $this->drive_service->files->listFiles();
```

Any thoughts?

Update Feb 21, 2017:  The error is no longer intermittent, it happens every time, so I can no longer connect at all to a regular account through a service account.

Update March 10, 2017:  It seems as though this is a user misunderstanding.  The service account must be given "domain-wide authority" in order to impersonate users of that domain - something I have not done.  I had simply authorized a client to access the users account as described [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/801#issuecomment-171417538).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your error happens periodically but my understanding is that to impersonate an user, you must [grant the service account access](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error intermittently when the account that's being impersonated is newly created.  By the looks of it, adding a 10 second delay before trying to create the service eliminates the problem.

Comment: The user account being impersonated is not newly created.