# accessing google drive api service account fails sometimes

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

in into google drive api with service account credential, to upload file for a specific user j********@gmail.com.

I create my account service credential in google developer API console.
i add permission for user j****@gmail.com
i authorize my app for j****@gmail.com

but sometimes autetication fails
with this messagge

```
Google_Service_Exception

{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

here's my code for auth

```
if ($credentials_file = checkServiceAccountCredentialsFile()) {
  // set the location manually
  $client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);
} elseif (getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')) {
  // use the application default credentials
  $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
} else {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
  return;
}
$client->setSubject('j******@gmail.com');
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files = $service->files->listFiles();
```

Comment: You need to clarify when "sometimes" is, as a way to identify what the problem is.

Comment: sometimes means if i refresh page, one times on three or four i have the error, it's a little bit strange, thanks a lot Gianmaria

Comment: here is the link, just to have an idea 
http://advertising.fortale.it/basic/web/

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903578/google-api-service-account-authorization-error.  Is no longer intermittent for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google API Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) to create web server applications that use OAuth 2.0 authorization to access Google APIs. Also, web applications frequently also use [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) when making API calls, particularly when calling Cloud APIs to access project-based data rather than user-specific data. These mechanisms can be used in conjunction with user authorization in a web server application.

Regarding you error *[`unauthorized_client`](http://apiwiki.poken.com/authentication/oauth2)*, it usually occurs in case the request failed to pass validation. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42067639/5832311), if you use Oauth2 you need to have a refresh token for each user who will be using your application. You can check this [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/) on how OAuth2 works.